# Check if callable can receive class as parameter in php

Tags: php, types, callable

I have a callable `$f` and I would like to know if it can receive an instance of a certain class `Foo` as input.

At the moment I'm doing something like

```
try {
    $f($foo);
} catch (\TypeError $e) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The provided function can not evaluate inputs of this type');
}
```

Is there a way to check this WITHOUT actually invoking the callable? Maybe with reflection or some other dark magic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to reflect any kind of callable, you'll need to wrap up the logic in a small function. Depending on whether you've got an array, a function name or an anonymous function, you need to create either a [`ReflectionFunction`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) or [`ReflectionMethod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php). Fortunately, these both extend [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunctionabstract.php), so we can type-hint the return value.

```
function reflectCallable($arg): ReflectionFunctionAbstract {
    if (is_array($arg)) {
        $ref = new ReflectionMethod(...$arg);
    } elseif (is_callable($arg)) {
        $ref = new ReflectionFunction($arg);
    }

    return $ref;
}
```

This will return you the appropriate object for your callable value, which you can then use to fetch the parameters and act accordingly:

```
function definedFunc(Foo $foo) {}
$callable = function(Foo $foo) {};
class Bar { public function baz(Foo $foo) {} }

foreach (['definedFunc', $callable, ['Bar', 'baz']] as $callable) {
    $reflected = reflectCallable($callable);

    if ((string) $reflected->getParameters()[0]->getType() === 'Foo') {
        echo 'Callable takes Foo', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

See https://3v4l.org/c5vmM

Note that this doesn't do any error handling - you'll probably get warnings/notices if the callable doesn't take any parameters or the first parameter doesn't have a type. It also requires PHP 7+, but hopefully that's not an issue.

<s>It doesn't currently support objects that implement `__invoke` or static calls defined as `"Foo::bar"`, but they wouldn't be too hard to add if necessary.</s> I've just found something very similar in the source of Twig, which does a more thorough job: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v2.8.0/src/Node/Expression/CallExpression.php#L280

Comment: thanks for the answer! Now I'm wandering which approach is faster, catching the exception or using reflection...

Answer (score 2):

You can with [ReflectionParameter::getType](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php):

```
$f = function(Foo $foo) {};

$reflectionFunc = new ReflectionFunction($f);
$reflectionParams = $reflectionFunc->getParameters();
$reflectionType1 = $reflectionParams[0]->getType();

echo $reflectionType1;
```

output:

> Foo

Comment: can I do this for every callable? I guess this just works for functions

Comment: `ReflectionFunction` works for functions (including anonymous ones). You can use `ReflectionMethod` if it's part of a class instead - it takes an object/class name as the first argument, and the method name as the second.

Comment: @marcosh yes it is possible and I've updated to match question better

Comment: a callable could be also an array with a class name and a method name. I don't think you can handle that easily with reflection

Comment: @marcosh You can unpack the array and pass it to ReflectionMethod instead - https://3v4l.org/ogFKT

Comment: I'm sorry if I've guessed as to what you meant by callable, if you were to update your question then I may update my question further to reflect that

Comment: @Barry it's standard terminology: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php