# PHP How to get function parameters, when function is passed as parameter

Tags: php

I want to do something like this:

```
function func($callback) {
    $result = $callback(???);    // $callback must be called here
    //...
}

//...
func(function(['foo' => 'buu']) {
    $a = func_get_arg(0);

    // do something with $a and return something...    
    return $something;       
})
```

It is possible in php?

I can do something like below, but this is not what I want to do:

```
function func($args, $callback) {
    $result = $callback($args);
    //...
}

func(['foo' => 'boo'], function($args) {
     $a = $args; // etc.
})
```

Comment: It seems to me like `['foo' => 'boo']` is being set where the callback is set, so why not just assign `$a` to `['foo' => 'boo']` in the callback instead of trying to use `func_get_arg(0);`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200682/check-if-callable-can-receive-class-as-parameter-in-php/52200757#52200757

Comment: @Davіd: You're right. But this is only stupid example.

Comment: @Barry. Thank You, this solved my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use anonymous function this ways :

```
$mySuperFunction = function($arg)
{
    echo ("Hello " . $arg);
};

function AnotherFunction($args)
{
    echo ("Another hello " . $args);
}

function WrappingAnonymous($callback, $args)
{
    $callback($args);
}

function WrappingAnonymousWithoutArgs($callback)
{
    $callback();
}

WrappingAnonymous($mySuperFunction, "World");
WrappingAnonymous("AnotherFunction", "World");
WrappingAnonymous(function($someArgs)
{
    echo "Yet another Hello " . $someArgs;
}, "World");


WrappingAnonymousWithoutArgs(function($someArgs = "World")
{
    echo "Now, a 4th other Hello " . $someArgs;
});
```

Outputs :

> Hello World
>
> Another hello World
>
> Yet another Hello World
>
> Now, a 4th other Hello World